# why is the drop down menu is overlapping with the text?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap classes and I don't know why is the The drop down menu is overlaping with the text
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sRO2.png)

````
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right d-block d-sm-none row">
                <li class="li-Menu text-center">Chiken</li ><hr">
                <li class="li-Menu text-center">Beef</li><hr">
                <li class="li-Menu text-center">Sushi</li>
            </ul>
          </div>```


There was a me-auto class , I removed it and I searched more and there seem to be no answer
````

Comment: Do you mean that the menu should have a background color?  Where do you set that?  Or do you mean something else?  Please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The drop down menu is showing on top of the following text

Comment: I added an answer for you my friend. Test it and if it works let me know

Comment: Sorry but it's still showing on top of the text –

Comment: Test the edited code in my answer

Comment: It's still didn't work . I will test what's above it . Thank you so much brother

Comment: The code I added to my post is essentially the webpage you made, except that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes
And that is very easy to fix

Add the following css code to your css

```
#navbarSupportedContent {z-index:99;}
```

Or if you prefer using the classname

```
.collapse {z-index:99;}
```

This will make the drop-down be more important and display on top when opening it

Edit: try the following:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" tabindex=”0” style=”z-index:10;”>
```

Comment: Sorry but it's still showing on top of  the text

Answer (score 1):

Fixing this is simple. Your navabar dropdown is below the elements. If you add `.collapse { z-index: 1000; }` it will be displayed above the other elements.

You should also do `.collapse { background-color: white }` to make sure you don't see anything below it.

If you want it to move elements under it so that you can see them, add this: `.collapse { display: block }` If those elements are absolutely positioned, then I don't really know how to move them.

Edit: [@Marcus Petersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4633687/marcus-petersen) asked me to add the code for it to work, so here it is.

CODE:

```js
var opened = false;
function openclose() {
    if (opened == true) {
        document.getElementById("openclose").innerHTML = "[Click] Open";
        document.getElementById("collapse").style.height = "0%";
        opened = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("openclose").innerHTML = "[Click] Close";
        document.getElementById("collapse").style.height = "250px";
        opened = true;
    }
}
```

```css
.collapseable {
    width: 100%;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
}
.collapseable p {
    text-align: center;
}
.collapseable {
    position: absolute; /* Change to block to move the stuff below it down */
    height: 0%;
    overflow-y: clip;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: height 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <nav>
      <button class="menu" onclick="openclose()">
          <span>Menu</span>
          <br>
          <span id="openclose">[Click] Open</span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapseable" id="collapse">
          <p>Menu Item 1</p>
          <hr>
          <p>Menu Item 2</p>
          <hr>
          <p>Menu Item 3</p>
      </div>
  </nav>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (and then more lorem)</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately  nothing changed

Comment: Are you sure the css is linked? That's the only thing I can think of that would be preventing it. Could you add the full HTML and CSS to the body of the question?

Comment: Test my edited answer and if that does not work then it is better if you add the css you have to your question because both answers should work in any case escenario

Comment: Yes it is linked . the other css code works fine

Comment: Like I said before, you should add the HTML and CSS to your question. Remember to always have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Mark the code that worked for you or write it here so users with the same problem can get help from this same question. Because right now users reading this for help with similar questions will not understand how to fix it

Comment: @MarcusPetersen I updated the post to include the code.

Comment: I told the other guy to post the code (Yeser Hmidi) to the question, but thanks for posting it. And yes in your answer we see it working just perfect.

Comment: Oh! I thought you were talking to me, because it was in my answer chat and not tagged to him. Although, this probably helps other people reading it too!